# Automating definition of tables and columns creating an RDBMS from a stats package like SPSS

Tags: sql, r, rdbms, spss

What is a good tool to use to automate or semi-automate (ie give a good headstart) the process of taking a rectangle of data from a statistics package like SPSS and:

- saving the main rectangle data in text format that can be read by a database
- saving additional files for other reference tables (eg value labels)
- drafting (probably to be polished up by hand) a script or batch file with the SQL to create the tables and columns in a database and import the text files as rows of data in the relevant tables?

I doubt full automation is possible but this must be a reasonably common task.  We have about a dozen such datasets, some with several hundred variables, that we want to set up in a relational database (Oracle, if that makes any difference).  There is no conceptual difficulty in doing this by hand other than prohibitive cost.

I feel there must be such a tool available but I am clearly searching in the wrong places or using the wrong terminology.

(edit - added the R tag because in my own answer to this I am using it as part of the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after further investigation (and thanks for the answer I was given, which was helpful although not quite fully there), I now favour:

1. bringing the data into R eg with the foreign package
2. Creating a data frame for each reference table I need
3. Replacing the original factor with an `as.numeric()` or `unclass()` version, so it is just the numbers, not the labels
4. saving both the main data and the reference tables to the database using `sqlSave()` from the RODBC package.

Step 2 is facilitated by a little function like this:

```
factorToRef <- function(x, field){
    tmp <- levels(x)
    tab <- data.frame(1:length(tmp), tmp)
    names(tab) <- paste(field, c("_ID","_NAME"), sep="")
    tab
}
```

Which can give results like

```
> data(iris)
> factorToRef(iris$Species, "species" )
  species_ID species_NAME
1          1       setosa
2          2   versicolor
3          3    virginica
```

That are then the basis of a reference table to be saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

In SPSS Statistics, the Output Management System (OMS) can capture any output table as a dataset.  And Statistics can write a dataset back directly to a database, or it can be saved as a CSV file or other formats.  See SAVE TRANSLATE for the latter.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  However it looks as though it will save a file as a single table.  I am interested in a situation where I have many questions with answers coded 1 to 5 and I want to keep the data as 1 to 5 but linked to a reference table that stores the value labels ie 1 = "strongly disagree", 2= "disagree", etc.  This would be much more efficient than storing the original variable as a string.  Perhaps I am too lazy if expecting a tool to do all this for me.